# T-SQL concatenate rows into string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use a sub query on a select statement for a field value but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.  I want to pull a list of company names and as a field for that query, I want to select all the employees for that company.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  The error I get is

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

T-SQL code:

```
SELECT 
   company_name, 
   company_type, 
   (SELECT 
        employee_firstname, employee_lastname 
    FROM 
        tblemployees 
    WHERE 
        tblemployees.company_id = tblCompanies.company_id) as employees 
FROM 
    tblCompanies
```

Desired output:

```
Company Name |  Company Type  | Employees
----------------------------------------------------------
Test Co      |  Construction  | Bob Smith, Jack Smith, etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to concatenate the first and last names using `FOR XML PATH` or a similar solution. More details on the various methods [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129484).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   c1.company_name, 
   c1.company_type,
   STUFF((SELECT
              ', ' + c2.employee_firstname + ' ' + c2.employee_lastname
          FROM
              tblCompanies c2
          WHERE
              c1.company_id = c2.company_id
          ORDER BY
              employee_lastname, employee_firstname
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM tblCompanies c1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8218/2)

Comment: Thank you sir for that information.  That worked perfectly, extremely help.  Thanks again.